# :selected pseudoclass style not applied to cell

Tags: java, css, javafx, css-selectors

I have some TableView in a Scene, where I want to highlight the cells that are selected. According to the [JavaFX CSS reference](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/doc-files/cssref.html), there is a pseudoclass `:selected` on Cells, so I tried the following css:

```
.cell:selected {
    -fx-effect: dropshadow(gaussian, 10, .2, 4, 4);
}
```

But the style is not applied to the cell. When I use `.cell:hover` it works as expected.

The following is a simplified FXML:

```xml
<Pane fx:controller="Controller">
   <children>
        <TableView fx:id="table" />
   </children>
</Pane>
```

I'm using this as controller:

```
public class Controller implements Initializable{
    @FXML
    private TableView<SomeClass> table;
    // some other things

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle bundle) {
        Objects.requireNonNull(table, "Table was not injected");
        // create columns, initialize other stuff
        table.getColumns().clear();
        table.getColumns().addAll(/*some columns */);
        table.setEditable(false);
        table.getSelectionModel().setSelectionMode(SelectionMode.SINGLE);
        table.setColumnResizePolicy(TableView.CONSTRAINED_RESIZE_POLICY);
    }
}
```

Why does the CSS not get applied to selected cells?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem here is the way JavaFX handles selection for cells and rows.

Let's consult the javadoc of [`TableViewSelectionModel`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/TableView.TableViewSelectionModel.html) for a moment, especially the `cellSelectionEnabled` property:

> A boolean property used to represent whether the table is in row or cell selection modes. By default a table is in row selection mode which means that individual cells can not be selected. Setting `cellSelectionEnabled` to be true results in cells being able to be selected (but not rows).

We can conclude, that your Cells are not marked as selected because you're in row-selection mode.
You can work around this by adjusting your css selector to rely on the row (something like this):

```
.table-row-cell:selected .cell {
    -fx-effect: ...;
}
```

You can make this even more useful in combination with `:cell-selection` and `:row-selection` on TableView:

```
.table-view:row-selection .table-row-cell:selected .cell, .table-view:cell-selection .cell:selected {
    -fx-effect: ...;
}
```

Will apply to selected cells, regardless of the modus operandi of your `TableViewSelectionModel`